# SQL query in SQLite / DB browser returning no values

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I can't seem to get a basic SQL query to work in SQLite. It's just a single 8 column table in db-browser for sqlite. Some of the data-types aren't correct here, but it shouldn't impact end results

I'm getting no results returned, it should be 116 results.

Data represented in SQLite

[image]

Basic SQL statement

[image]

```
select
    `CountyName`,
    gender,
    sum(population)
from secondTable
where Year = 2014
group by `CountyName`, gender
order by `CountyName`, gender
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears your "year" column is defined as type "TEXT".

If the rows where year is 2014 are actually "2014.0" (like all of the 2010 examples your picture shows), then the WHERE clause isn't going to match on them.

Answer (score 1):

Sqllite doesnt have a datetime type, so for comparison you have to so this:

```
select
    `CountyName`,
    gender,
    sum(population)
from secondTable
where Year = “2014”
group by `CountyName`, gender
order by `CountyName`, gender
```

If you have an actual date, there are functions like `strftime`